# Always get last object in shared nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a shared nsmutablearray in my application. I'm pulling a bunch of data from an sqlite db and adding to the array. The array has the correct number of objects as the DB, but when I call objectAtIndex I always get the same value - the last record values.

So I'm unsure if my app is failing at adding to the shared array or pulling data from it. Here's some code: The last two NSLog's give me the same output, which is incorrect

```
SYSAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SYSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    Contra *contra = [[Contra alloc]init];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    int recordCount = 0;



    if (sqlite3_open([appDelegate.dbPathString UTF8String], &_DB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        [appDelegate.array removeAllObjects];

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM DATATABBLE"];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(_DB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *start = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSString *stop = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSString *cTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                NSString *intensity = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                NSString *timeElapsed = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                NSString *hour = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];



                [contra setStartDate:start];
                [contra setStopDate:stop];
                [contra setIntensity:[intensity intValue]];
                [contra setCTime:[cTime intValue]];
                [contra setTimeElapsed:[timeElapsed intValue]];
                [contra setHour:[hour intValue]];



                [appDelegate.array addObject:contra];
                recordCount++;

            }

        }
    }


    //Get data from array

    //Get last object
    contra = [appDelegate.array lastObject];

    NSLog(@"cont length: %i.", contra.cTime);


    //Get an earlier object
    contra = [appDelegate.array objectAtIndex:recordCount -2];
    NSLog(@"two cont length: %i", contra.cTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've synthesized the properties of Contra class.

I'd better suggest you to put  Contra *contra = [[Contra alloc]init]; statement inside while loop and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through a while loop and assigning the new values to properties of the same contra object at every interation. Effectively your NSMutableArray has the same object at every location, and each iteration is changing property values of the same object. Therefore you will get the same values at every index that you test against - the last property values that you set on the object.

Move the statement Contra *contra = [[Contra alloc]init]; inside the while loop. Then each of the objects in the array will be unique and you will get the correct results.